# PySys ProcessMonitor timestamps use different formats on Windows and Linux

Tags: python, performance-testing

We're using PySys partly for performance testing, including the ProcessMonitor class to monitor CPU and memory usage, and a part of our tests parses the timestamp in the first column of the ProcessMonitor output, which requires us knowing the exact format. We run our tests on both Windows and Linux and have found that the format string is different on each platform's implementation of ProcessMonitor ("**%d/%m**/%y %H:%M:%S" on Windows and "**%m/%d**/%y %H:%M:%S" on Linux, with the month/day flipped).

We're on 1.1, though I see this issue is not yet patched in 1.2, the current latest version. Easy enough to patch on our own, but of course preferable to have it rolled into a future version. Thanks!

Comment: What is your actual question? This seems to me like it should be a [bug report](https://sourceforge.net/p/pysys/bugs/) upstream. The date formats are hardcoded in the platform files ([linux](https://sourceforge.net/p/pysys/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/pysys/process/plat-unix/monitor.py#l153), [windows](https://sourceforge.net/p/pysys/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/pysys/process/plat-win32/monitor.py#l204)), I'm not sure what we on SO could do in this case.

Answer (score 0):

This is an inconsistency in the framework as pointed out, thanks. I've added a defect to the project so it can be tracked there (https://sourceforge.net/p/pysys/bugs/15) and we can take offline from SO.